# Can I use (only) the Super key as a shortcut?

Tags: 10.04, shortcut-keys, shortcuts

Usually in Gnome and KDE it is only possible to define shortcuts with the <kbd>Super</kbd> key in combination with another key. But is it possible to use *only* the <kbd>Super</kbd> key as a shortcut, and how could I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can. You can fill with **Super_L** to the shortcut you want, for example to use **win key only** for launching gnome menu :

open terminal, type :

> `gconftool-2 –set
>   /apps/metacity/global_keybindings/panel_main_menu
>   –type string “Super_L”`

The gnome menu will lauch with windows key only.

Comment: This doesn't work in my case (Ubuntu 10.04). However it works, if I edit the panel_main_menu entry in the gconf-editor.

Comment: You have en-dashes (looks like) and angled quotes rather than "plain" double quotes there, so copy-pasting this directly won't work.  (However, no quotes are needed here.)

Comment: `gconftool-2 --set /apps/metacity/global_keybindings/panel_main_menu --type string Super_L`

Answer (score 2):

The *Super* key is a so-called *modifier* key, i.e., it is only meaningful in combination with some other key (it "modifies" the other key to report *Super+key* instead of just *key*).  This makes it impossible to bind it to a shortcut with the System->Preferences->Keyboard shortcuts GUI without a tweak.

You can tell the system to not consider *Super* a modifier key any longer; then you will be able to map it to any shortcut you want.

1. In a terminal, type the command `xmodmap`; it will output a few lines -- look for the one that has `Super_L` and `Super_R` in it. It should look like this:

   ```
   mod4        Super_L (0x85),  Super_R (0x86),  Super_L (0xce)
   ```

   See the `mod4` at the beginning of the line? That means that `Super_L` and `Super_R` (left- and right- *Super* keys) are bound to the 4th modifier (there are 8 in total).
2. If you want to be able to bind the `Super_R` key,  give the command (note the quotes!):

   ```
   xmodmap -e 'remove mod4 = Super_R'
   ```

   This tells X11 that right-*Super* should no longer be a modifier.

*Note:* These settings will not survive a reboot; you can make them permanent
by creating a text file `.Xmodmap` in your home directory, and writing a single
line to it:

```
 remove mod4 = Super_R
```