# Assign shift+tab to the control button on the right?

Tags: shortcut-keys

Is it possible to assign <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> to the control key on the right?

Comment: You know how you're on an Open/Save Dialog box? And you need to navigate backwards? That's shift+tab. I found when I was using Windows that remapping the right control key to shift+tab I was far more likely to use the keyboard to navigate through fields.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In X11 jargon, the name for a key is called its *keysym* (short for:
key symbol).  The keysym generated by <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>
is `ISO_Left_Tab`.  So, in theory, one could just assign the
`ISO_Left_Tab` keysym to any key (which you can do with the command
[xmodmap](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xmodmap)) and this would do the trick.

Unfortunately, some applications (for instance: Firefox) explicitly
look for the *Shift* keypress, and this breaks it, because you cannot
assign two keysyms (*Shift* and *Tab*) to one single key.

Fortunately, [Roger Pate's answer to this AskUbuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7769/keyboard-shortcut-for-pasting-the-primary-selection/7807#7807) provides
a way around it: bind a shortcut to a program that will simulate the
simultaneous pressing of *Shift* and *Tab*.

1. [Install the **xvkbd** package](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/xvkbd)
2. From the *System->Preferences->Keyboard shortcuts* menu, create a
   new shortcut, name it e.g. "Shift+Tab" and insert the following
   command:

   ```
   sh -c "xvkbd -text '\S\[ISO_Left_Tab]'"
   ```

   The purpose of this command is just to send a virtual Shift+Tab
   keystroke to the currently focused window. (Consult the [xvbkd man
   page](http://man-wiki.net/index.php/1x:xvkbd) for more information.)
3. Bind this shortcut to any key you want.  Note that, to bind a
   shortcut to a *modifier* key (i.e., one that is only meaningful in
   combination with another key, for instance *Shift* or *Alt*) you
   need to deprive it of its modifier status.  For example, before
   binding *right-Control*, you need to issue this command in a
   terminal:

   ```
   xmodmap -e 'remove control = Control_R'
   ```

   (See [this other AskUbuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7715/can-i-use-only-the-super-key-as-a-shortcut) for another way to bind
   modifier keys.)

   Note: the xmodmap line above will only have effect until next reboot/logout. To make it persistent, you would have to either put that line into the `~/.gnomerc` file, or add `remove control = Control_R` to the `~/.Xmodmap` file.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. I did follow the instructions, but strangely it only worked once, then stopped altogether. Control_R is definitely stripped of its modifier status, so I'm at a bit of a loss. (Could this have something to do with having Autokey installed?)

Comment: @begtognen I do not know much about Autokey, so I cannot help there. However, the `xmodmap` line that I pasted will only last until next reboot/logout.  To make it persistent, you would have to either put that line into the `~/.gnomerc` file, or add `remove control = Control_R` to the `~/.Xmodmap` file.

Comment: Oops! Sorry, I wasn't very clear - I meant that it literally worked one time, then never worked again. Not that I restarted the computer, but that it worked once, then I immediately tried it again, and no luck.

Comment: @begtognen Does it work consistently, if you bind it to a different, non-modifier key?  E.g., `Pause`

Comment: I tried binding it to a few different non-modifier keys. While I couldn't get it to even work once, oddly I did see that *something* was happening: the field I was in would flash whenever I hit the keyboard shortcut.

Comment: @begtognen: I've double-checked: the steps outlined in the answer work fine on my computers (Lucid & Maverick)... What do you get if you run `xev` and hit your intended-Shift-Tab key in the `xev` window? (Consider using http://paste.ubuntu.com to list output.)

Comment: I really appreciate all of your info. I think the problem must be unique to my computer; this time the keyboard just stopped working altogether. Obviously I'm not meant to reassign shift+tab. Hee. I think I'll let it go for now. Thanks so much for the info, though.